# how are objects stored and handled in java internal?

Tags: java, memory, operating-system

I need some kind of documentation how the access to java objects is handled?

e.g.:

- what happens when an object is updated?
- how does java find and index the elements in the memory?

Thank you

Comment: Consult the JVM spec perhaps http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html

Comment: Refer : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think google is the best way to find it, but you can try to look [here](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvmP.html).